# Change collection key

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to replace collection key with new one. Here is what I do but don't get what I expected. I want to replace the number 1, 3 with the `date_rapport` attribute. Thank you in advance.

**The main collection query:**

```
 $rapports = DB::table('sta_rapports_jaugeage')
                    ->select(
                        'date_rapport',
                        'id_cuve',
                        'id_article',
                        DB::raw("SUM(qte_physique_initial) as qtePhysiqueIni"),
                        DB::raw("SUM(qte_physique_final) as qtePhysique")
                    )
                    ->whereIn('id_cuve', $filtre_cuves)
                    ->whereIn('id_article', $filtre_prod)
                    ->whereIn('id_rapport', $filtre_id)    
                    ->groupBy('date_rapport')
                    ->groupBy('id_article')
                    ->get()
                    ->keyBy('date_rapport');

$rapportssdds = $rapports->map(function ($rapport, $key) {
                    $key = $rapport->date_rapport;
                    $collect_rep = collect([$key => $rapport]);
                    return $collect_rep;
                });
```

Here is a screenshot of the collection
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to use the `date_rapport` field as the `key`, try using the [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) method:

```php
$rapports->groupBy('date_rapport');
```

That will group the `items` in your `$rapports` collection by the `date_rapport` field. So if there is multiple items with the same date, they will be grouped together with the date as the key and all items with the same `data_rapport` value as its children.

**Update**

```php
$rapports = DB::table('sta_rapports_jaugeage')
            ->select(
                'date_rapport',
                'id_cuve',
                'id_article',
                DB::raw("SUM(qte_physique_initial) as qtePhysiqueIni"),
                DB::raw("SUM(qte_physique_final) as qtePhysique")
            )
            ->whereIn('id_cuve', $filtre_cuves)
            ->whereIn('id_article', $filtre_prod)
            ->whereIn('id_rapport', $filtre_id)
            ->groupBy('date_rapport', 'id_article')
            ->get();
```

That should group your records by `date_rapport` and then `id_article`.

You don't need to then use `map()` on `$rapports`, you can just use the above if you need to.

Comment: Thank you too @Peppermintology for replying , i already do that, i update my post adding the main query.

Comment: You don't need to use `map()` to achieve what you're asking. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok @Peppermintology i'll try and let you know. Thank you

Comment: It's work as espected @Peppermintology thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use [`keyBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keyby):

```
$rapportssdds = $rapports->keyBy('date_rapport');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @shaedrich, i already try that but the problem  on. the same date we can have two item with differente values.

Comment: I can't see what your problem is. If you need more logic, you can pass a callback function to `keyBy()`.

Comment: Ok i'll try that , the problem  on the image you can see values of  collection different on the same date for exemple "id_article', when i apply keyBy i get only one date last one.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the key does. Maybe you need [`groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) instead.

Comment: I update just updat my question to add the main query.

Comment: To see how to use `groupBy()` see @Peppermintology's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67722810/7451109)